# ubuntu 17.04 cmake x265

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, cmake

I try to compile x265 on ubuntu 17.04, I got error

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/x265/build/linux
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" -DENABLE_SHARED:bool=off ../../source
make
```

Error

```
[ 62%] Built target common
[ 63%] Building CXX object encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/analysis.cpp.o
In file included from /root/ffmpeg_sources/x265/source/encoder/analysis.cpp:35:0:
/root/ffmpeg_sources/x265/source/encoder/encoder.h:34:36: fatal error: dynamicHDR10\hdr10plus.h: No such file or directory
 #include "dynamicHDR10\hdr10plus.h"
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/analysis.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/analysis.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:224: recipe for target 'encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I try by Googling but I can't find how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in source/encoder/encoder.h

You can change this:

```
#include "dynamicHDR10\hdr10plus.h"
```

to this:

```
#include "dynamicHDR10/hdr10plus.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo in the script that you can edit before running 'make':

Just like it says, the x265/source/encoder/encoder.h file tries to include "dynamicHDR10\hdr10plus.h" but there is "No such file" because it is "dynamicHDR10/hdr10plus.h" (hdr10plus.h) in the x265/source/dynamicHDR10 directory.